# откуда брать значение object_id при выдаче предмета в Lineage2?

Tags: sql, gameserver

Возникла необходимость выдавать итемы(вещи, адена и т.д.) в игре Lineage2. Возник вопрос: в базе игрового сервера (сервер на `java`) имеется таблица `items`, в которую записываются все итемы(вещи, ресурсы, деньги и т.д.), которые находятся у игроков. Значение в столбце `object_id`, как я понял, это уникальный `id` вещи, который должен равняться максимальному `object_id+1` для новой вещи. Проблема в том, что в один момент в игре может генерироваться куча этих `object_id` и далеко не все из них попадают в таблицу `items`. Причем даже если смотреть на таблицу `items` и выбить например шмотку с монстра игрового, то при выпадении шмотка имеет один `оbject_id` (и находится в другой таблице - `itemsonground`), после того как поднимешь другой `object_id`, причем даже когда быстро поднимаешь и я один на сервере, то `object_id` поднятой вещи не равен `object_id-1` выбитой. А может быть на `+30`, `+59`, и т.д. отличаться. А если не присваивать этот `object_id`, то выдать вещь можно всего лишь раз, после этого, при выполнении следующего `sql` запроса, возникает исключение о том, что `object_id have primary key.....` в общем, так больше не прокатит. Если у вас был подобный опыт, напишите, как вы это делали.
[image: на фото таблица в navicat]

Comment: Скорее всего где то должен быть справочник всех предметов, на который ссылаются другие таблицы. На скриншоте есть колоночка `item_id`, возможно стоит попытаться от нее крутиться?

Comment: А может быть у автора сборки узнать это? Ведь сборки разные бывают и у них таблицы в БД даже разные бывают и даже разнесены на несколько баз.....у некоторых `itemsonground` отстутствует....

Comment: команды этой сборки я так понял уже нет. От item_id тоже врятли, так как одинаковые вещи имеют разный object_id

Comment: В общем пока ничего лучше, чем брать с базы максимальный object_id и плюсовать к нему (в моем случае +11), не придумал.А потом получившееся писать в базу к выдаваемой вещи.